# Affine hull and relative interior

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

If I have two nonempty, compact and convex sets in a vector space, say $A$ and $B$, such that $\textrm{aff}(A) = \textrm{aff}(B)$, is it true that $\textrm{relint}(A) \subseteq B$ (or viceversa)?

Comment: Have you tried any simple examples? Take $A$ to be the convex hull of $(1,0), (1,1)$ and $B$ to be the convex hull of $(-1,0),(-1,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat yes, I was thinking almost the same. It seems not working in general.